# Win 8 32 bits ... why?

Tags: windows-8-preview

With the development of 64 bits systems, hardwares, softwares, why the newest windows 8 still have 32 bits option ??
Considering that since 2003, virtually all x86 CPUs already have 64-bit instructions ??

Comment: Vosting to close, since only the people responsible for this decision will be able yo answer your question.

Comment: Your question is for Microsoft, not for us. We can't answer it, although the reasons seems to be clear.

Comment: I suspect the only real argument is their insistence that it'll run on EVERY SINGLE MACHINE that Windows 7 would.

Answer (score 2):

One case would be you only have 32-bit device drivers for some hardware you need.  Maybe some telephony boards or industrial data acquisition and control.  For the consumer, it's probably not likely you'll need the 32-bit version these days except maybe an old printer.